# understanding Xcode debugger var display

Tags: xcode

newbie question: can anyone tip me to how to understand/interpret what is displayed in the debugger var pane?

Ex: I am passing an NSDictionary as a method param. I set a breakpoint so I can examine the values in the dictionary. The image below (if it comes through..) shows the expanded view of this var in the debugger. It correctly reports that it contains 3 name/value pairs but as I expand all the sections, I simply can not find where these are stored.

Do I have to create local vars of these name/value pairs in order to view them when I want to check? I know I can use NSLog or printf but sometimes I just want a quick peek.

[image: dictionary var in debugger]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Right click the variable, click "Edit Summary Format" and type the following:

```
{(NSString*)[$VAR description]}:s
```

This replaces the GDB formatter for NSDictionary with a call to the more expensive description method.
That is, instead "x key/value pairs", you'll see the contents of the dictionary as produced by -[NSDictionary description].

This is the same as typing `po dictionary` in the console window. Or right clicking the variable and choosing "Print Description". Both of them call the description method of the object.

---

If you are curious, you can find this formatter at `/Developer/Library/Xcode/CustomDataViews/Foundation.plist` under the key NSDictionary. What you type as replacement is saved in `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/Debugger/CustomDataFormatters` and will persist across runs until you delete that file.

A NSDictionary is really a class cluster and few people know the inside structure. At this point you ain't going to find much use for that debugger tree.

Comment: thanks - the right click/print description does the job for me.

Comment: This link gives some more description: http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/220-Viewing_Variables_and_Memory/variables_and_memory.html

Answer (score -1):

This is what you are looking for :
Click on your dict, then click on the little "i" icon :-)
[image: Xcode5, view the value of a dict]