# Why does Xcode 4.2 not show values of variables in debug mode when hovering over them?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

Xcode 3.2 showed me the values of variables. Now in Xcode 4.2 when I debug and it stopped in a scope, I can't see the values of variables anymore. The variables view on the lower left side contains almost nothing useful except the memory adress of an object. When I click the expand-arrow nothing appears there. It's empty.

Must I setup something to make the debugger work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 4 is very finicky with variables in the debug window. You'll probably find that locally defined primitives (ints, floats, strings, etc) will display but nothing else will.

I know its not much help but I usually just add an 'NSLog()' and print the variables I am trying to debug. Not as convenient but it gets the job done.

If anyone else knows a permanent fix id also be grateful.

Comment: Not without work, but here is one way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758664/understanding-xcode-debugger-var-display/7761601#7761601

Comment: some tips for debugging: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/debugging-tips-for-objective-c.html

Comment: Note that CWL's debugging tut is based on GDB. Xcode4 uses LLVM and it's companion debugger.

Comment: If you type 'po variableName' in the debugger you can print an objects value. You also get autocomplete for variable and class names. I find this is the best way to print my variables.

Comment: Another tut for debugging (with LLVM) can be found at mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/debugging-in-ios-essential-tips/

Answer (score 1):

If you right click in the lower left view you can select "Add Expression" and type the name of the variable.

Why Xcode cannot display this information when hovering over is a mystery to me.