# Get value of NSTaggedPointerString

Tags: xcode, debugging, nstaggedpointerstring

I'm trying to debug my program, and I have a dictionary that I'm trying to inspect in the debugger; however, when I view the dictionary in the debugger, it looks like this:

[image: Debugger]

Most of the keys are listed as `NSTaggedPointerString` and I'm not able to see the value. Why is this and how can I get the value of the keys?

Comment: Right-click on the key and select "Print Description Of xxx".

Comment: @rmaddy that worked. If you want to make it the answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [understanding Xcode debugger var display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758664/understanding-xcode-debugger-var-display)

Comment: @rmaddy has shown you how to see the value, for an idea of where this type is coming from see [Mike Ash's Tagged Pointer Strings](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-07-31-tagged-pointer-strings.html) though by the look of it Apple may have updated the scheme.

Comment: I don't have the option "print description..." on my right click menu. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As [rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) said in the [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305177/get-value-of-nstaggedpointerstring#comment62132527_37305177), you can right-click on the key, or any NSTaggedPointerString in the Variables View and select "Print Description of VariableNameHere", and it will print out to the Console.

I'm just posting this as an answer to make it more obvious to people who need the answer, like me.